# Managed online outsourcing companies

Tags: freelance-websites, remote, outsourcing, working-from-home

I just stumbled upon a company called ZIP-Task. That company claims to realize online outsourcing projects in a different way than I have seen before. In conventional online outsourcing companies (e.g. oDesk, eLance, etc.) developers are more or less on their own.

ZIP-Task says the organise projects in a more systematical way (especially by first installing a project manager) but still selecting team members from an open freelancer pool on demand.

That special company seems a bit weird. For potential freelancers they even do not provide an explicit way of contacting them (e.g. by e-mail) other then applying for their pool. That creeps me out a little. Also they do not provide any detailed information for potential freelancers. At least I could not find anything.

Still the idea is interesting from a possible freelancer's point of view since I made *very* bad experiences with oDesk and similar sites (from a customer point of view). I think the ZIP task way may be a good idea. However I could not find any other companies that provide similar services.

Does someone have experiences with that special company?
Are there any other companies that realize a similar online outsourcing concept?

Comment: Skimmed it, seems interesting. I will explore it.

Comment: Surely that's how an agency works? Agency has a supply of freelancers, client approaches agency and asks for x to be done, agency manages project and picks people to do the job. Odesk does have support for agencies as far as I know.

Comment: This just seems off-topic to me. Not so much freelancing as a company review request.

Comment: Don't have traditional agencies a limited pool of freelancers that work in the agency or at the location of the customers? Are there agencies that actually use a pool of remote developers that work via internet only to realize *online* outsourcing? Even on oDesk such agencies are not built that way, are they?